# Covering challas by 3rd meal on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, meal-seudah, challah-shabbat-bread

We cover the challas by the shabbos meals for a number of reasons. One however is because the mann was covered (with dew) on top and on the bottom (See Tosfos Pesachim 100b) and the challas that we are eating are a rememberance of the mann. For this reason then seemingly we should cover the challas also by the third seudah. Are there people that do cover the challas then? If there isn't a minhag like this, why not?

Comment: The Rambam held such a view I believe.

Comment: Everywhere I've been (that I can think of) for the third meal has covered them. In large settings not every single one has always been covered, necessarily, but when people have taken them on their plates they've typically covered them (again, not every instance, but I always assume that is because they just didn't think of it or because there's no wine so they don't bother). Anyway, point is, it's very commonly done.

Comment: Aruch Hashulchan says there is no minhag

Comment: @sam No. He says that the people in his time and place didn't have that minhag. He doesn't say there is no such minhag.

Comment: Well if you see answer I said that

Answer (score 4):

Rivevos Ephraim 8:117:14 addresses this and says since there is no kiddush we don't cover the challahs.However,the Rambam(reasoning of the Tur )holds one does make kiddush.
The Aruch Hashulchan 291:10.we are noheg not to cover them.

The Ben Ish Chai Shana Beit Chayei Sarah 12 holds one has to cover the bread just like the night and day meal even though there is no kiddush by this meal since there are two other reasons which have nothing to do with kiddish(like the questioner mentioned)

Comment: The Rambam doesn't hold there's kidush, just that you drink wine during the meal--the Aruch hashulchan says this as well.

Comment: @wfb ,not so pashut see the Tur who holds such an opinion in 291:4 also see Bach.but it is debatable.